# No destruction phase in classes derived from abstract classes in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-functions

A co-worker of mine asked, why their tests were crashing. The exception description was "Pure virtual call". A quick review of the code (see below for an over-simplified example) showed that their tests were referencing objects created on the stack after their scope expired because they were keeping stale bare pointers. Easy.

Then my colleague asked, why did their tests run earlier, since the only thing she added (correctly, I might say) was the virtual destructor in the abstract class! Frankly I have no idea and I hope someone might enlighten me.

I've debugged the application and after removing the desctructor declaration from `IFooListener` the application runs fine, and the vftable pointer points to the vftable of the concrete class. Hence the program runs and the printfs print. Once the virtual destructor comes in, after the object exits its scope, the vftable pointer points to the vftable of the abstract class.

I also tried with a non-virtual destructor and the effect was the same - the application crashed and burned like it rightly should.

How should I understand this? 
If the destructor, virtual or not, is not declared and defined in the abstract class the base class destructor will not be generated and called to cleanup the vftable?

(Tested and debugged under Windows with VS2008 compiler)

Here's a simplified reconstruction of the troublesome code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

class IFooListener
{
public:
    virtual void onFoo() = 0;
    virtual ~IFooListener();
};

IFooListener::~IFooListener() {
    // nothing to do!
}

class TestListener : public IFooListener
{
public:
    TestListener()
    {
        m_FooCounter = 0;
    }
    virtual void onFoo()
    {
        ++m_FooCounter;
        printf("Got foo!\n");
    }
    unsigned int getFooCount()
    {
        return m_FooCounter;
    }
private:
    unsigned int m_FooCounter;
};

class FooSource
{
public:
    void sendFoo();
    void addListner(IFooListener * pListener);
private:
    std::vector<IFooListener *> m_Listeners;
};

void FooSource::sendFoo() 
{
    for (std::vector<IFooListener *>::const_iterator i = m_Listeners.begin(); i != m_Listeners.end(); i++)
    {
        IFooListener * listener = *i;
        listener->onFoo();
    }
}

void FooSource::addListner(IFooListener * a_pListener)
{
    m_Listeners.push_back(a_pListener);
}

void runTest(FooSource& source, int id)
{
    switch (id) {
case 1:
    {
        TestListener listener1;
        source.addListner(&listener1);
        source.sendFoo();
        if (0 == listener1.getFooCount())
        {
            printf("Test 1 failed!\n");
        }
        break;
    }
case 2:
    {
        TestListener listener1;
        TestListener listener2;
        source.addListner(&listener1);
        source.addListner(&listener2);
        source.sendFoo();
        if ((0 == listener1.getFooCount()) || (0 == listener2.getFooCount()))
        {
            printf("Test 2 failed!\n");
        }
        break;
    }
default:
        printf("Unknown test\n");
        break;
    }
}


int main()
{
    FooSource source;
    runTest(source, 1);
    runTest(source, 2);

    printf("Testing finished\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, so any number of things could affect the outcome. It isn't worth spending too much time reasoning it.

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you tried, so I can only guess what puzzles you. Anyhow, the first thing is that during destruction, the object changes its type, similarly to construction. That means that at some point the dynamic type is that of the abstract baseclass, including necessary adjustments to the effective virtual functions. The second thing is that the compiler can elide anything following the "as if" rule. In particular, when doing something causes undefined behaviour, it can assume that this just doesn't happen, like accessing objects after they are destroyed.

Comment: @juanchopanza trying to use an object after it went out of scope clearly yields undefined behaviour and that is clear. But is deriving from an abstract class with no explicit destructor declaration enough to enter the undefined realm?

Comment: OK, did you try without the virtual destructor *after* fixing the dangling pointer problem?

Comment: If I handle the dangling pointer problem, there will be nothing to consider anymore. You're probably right that this is not worth getting deeply into, I was just curious why it worked when it obviously shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing just the destructor question:

There is no *polymorphic* destruction happening here, so the lack of a virtual destructor in the parent doesn't prevent the child from being cleaned up. Specifically, the local `TestListener` has its own destructor called when it goes out of scope, because the compiler *already knows* the exact type of the object being destroyed! Since it knows the exact type, it doesn't need to use a virtual destructor to clean up the child instance.

The reason that it crashes in one case and doesn't crash (note: I don't say it worked because it *didn't work* - the results only appeared to work) is that both of those options are legitimate examples of undefined behavior. Practically speaking it's because the code to handle an abstract destructor call is different from that of a non-abstract call.

Comment: I know exactly why the program crashes. I want to know why it works when the explicitly declared destructor is removed from the abstract base class definition.